Codesandbox button working in preview but not in the tab
I am very new to coding and just want to play games on my school chromebook, so i stole a script and modified it loosely for a button that gets an about:blank tab open for slowroads.io, but the button does not work in the tab and only in the editor, but the editor is blocked for my school chromebooks. Any help?
i tried going through ChatGPT, but that didn't work and i can't figure it out. Here is my code.
<html>
  <head> </head>

  <body>
    <button>Play Now</button>
    <script>
      var urlObj = new window.URL(window.location.href);
      var url =
        "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxelPWLSDPiu3ayp2BRrr6gMa5dQHTHCWI6cqYGmiLgG-UL9-HuRQIwFzDywOUTZWUvCQ/exec";
      if (url) {
        var win;

        document.querySelector("button").onclick = function () {
          if (win) {
            win.focus();
          } else {
            win = window.open();
            win.document.body.style.margin = "0";
            win.document.body.style.height = "100vh";
            var iframe = win.document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.style.border = "none";
            iframe.style.width = "100%";
            iframe.style.height = "100%";
            iframe.style.margin = "0";
            iframe.src = url;
            win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
          }
          document.querySelector("button").style.bacground = "grey";
          document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = "Play Now";
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



What do you mean by "works in the preview"?  What is preview?

there is like a little preview of the page in the right side of the code editor so you can see what it looks like
